# Selenium Unable to locate element (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click the button with selenium headless webdriver

```
<button data-qa="STREAKS-QA_claim-button" class="css-19g9d2g" disabled=""><span class="css-kqn307"><span class="css-z2sz3e">Claim</span>&nbsp;<span class="css-1k2c4a5"><span class="infl-fe__styles__icon___3YFBO infl-fe__styles__coins___BelNu" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>&nbsp;2&nbsp;<span class="css-1f8ibv"><span class="infl-fe__styles__icon___3YFBO infl-fe__styles__check___l-v5z" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></span></button>
```

My Code

```
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-qa=STREAKS-QA_claim-button]")
element.click()
```

It's not working :(, need some advice.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Add the html/css code part that have the element you are trying to click

Comment: "It's not working" is not very helpful. Please post the actual/full error message, properly formatted along with the HTML already requested.

Comment: Got error :
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button[data-qa=STREAKS-QA_claim-button]"}

Answer (score 3):

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath/css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If this is a unique `button[data-qa=STREAKS-QA_claim-button]` then you need to check for the below conditions as well.

1. Check if it's in any `iframe/frame/frameset`.
2. Check if it's in any `shadow-root`.
3. Make sure that the element is rendered properly before interacting with it. Put some `hardcoded delay` or `Explicit wait` and try again.
4. If you have redirected to a `new tab/ or new windows` and you have not **switched** to that particular `new tab/new window`, otherwise you will likely get `NoSuchElement` exception.
5. If you have switched to an iframe and the new desired element is not in the same iframe context then first `switch to default content` and then interact with it.

Mostly if it is just an element rendered issue:

**Code trial 1:**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-qa=STREAKS-QA_claim-button]"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `'` in your locator.
Also you are probably missing a delay.
If so adding a dummy sleep of

```py
time.sleep(5)
```

Before

```py
element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-qa='STREAKS-QA_claim-button']")
element.click()
```

Should work.
However it is recommended to use Expected Conditions explicit waits here, something like this:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-qa='STREAKS-QA_claim-button']"))).click()
```

You will need these imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

To initialize the `wait` object you will have to do

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, I did miss out on the odd `' '` however I wrote this `button[data-qa=STREAKS-QA_claim-button]` in the browser console and could see the desired element is getting highlighted. any thought on this?

Answer (score 0):

The element is a ***dynamic*** element. So to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54193625/how-to-click-on-a-element-through-selenium-python/54194511#54194511) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48054321/of-the-many-findelements-by-functions-in-selenium-when-would-you-use-one-over/48056120#48056120):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-qa='STREAKS-QA_claim-button']>span[class^='css']>span[class^='css']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@data-qa='STREAKS-QA_claim-button']//span[text()='Claim']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```